# Renaming a DOMNode in PHP

Tags: php

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
<Document xmlns='urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02'>
    <books>    
        <book>
        <qty>12</qty>
        <title>C++</title>
        </book>
        <book>
        <qty>21</qty>
        <title>PHP</title>
        </book>    
      </books>    

      <books>    
        <book>
        <qty>25</qty>
        <title>Java</title>
        </book>    
        <book>  
        <qty>32</qty>
        <title>Python</title>
        </book>
        <book>  
        <qty>22</qty>
        <title>History</title>
        </book>    
    </books>

  </Document>
```

How Can I Rename ?

```
<Document xmlns='urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02'>
```

TO

```
<Document>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you don't rename, you remove an attribute. Maybe DomElement::removeAttribute (http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.removeattribute.php) will do the work BUT if he doesn't because xmlns defines a namespace try to redefine the default namespace to null.

Comment: yes,you right ,how can redefine the default namespace to null.